# Overlay divs without absolute positioning and resize distortion

Tags: html, css

I want to create a line with tick marks and a ball (like a scale).

However the tutorials for this suggest using absolute positioning, or float. That works partially, but when I change the screen size, the divs shift out of place.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
.point {
  -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 50px/50px;
  border: solid 21px #f00;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: -15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a div and do use absolute positioning for the inner divs, also, don't use margin-top percentages (https://jsfiddle.net/xv259d4p/1/):

```css
.line {
    width:100%;
    min-height:5px;
    background-color:black;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:60px;
    position: absolute;
}
.point {
    -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px/50px;
    border:solid 21px #f00;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
     float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding:20px;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;  

}
.outer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="line"> </div>
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your JSfiddle, the ball does not stay in the correct/same position, on browser resize.

Comment: What do you mean? It does on my end; that's the whole concept of absolute positioning.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle, maybe you're not seeing what I'm seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/xv259d4p/1/

Comment: My bad, forgot to actually save the changes I made ;). If this solution answers your question, please mark this one as so!

Comment: Okay, thank you I see it now. However it is using absolute positioning? Is there a way to perform this without absolute positioning. I'm afraid absolute positioning will cause the circle and square to float above the other content on the page.

For instance I am using a grid-based framework. Absolute positioning causes the shapes to float outside of the grid, making the framework useless.

Comment: They are inside of a div that is positioned relatively, meaning content can flow above en below it; the circle and line are positioned absolutely WITHIN their parent div.